# How to pass value of current PHP file to another PHP file by clicking a button?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to link one php file to another one. The first file, which is a query result of one mysql command, contains introduction of all the products.

[image]

When the "Details" button is clicked, I want the page to be redirected to another php file, which accepts the query result (ID, name) from the first file and output the detailed information.

Now I'm stuck at the "button" step. Could anyone help me to link the two files?

```
<div><button href = "Product_details.php" type="submit" name="Details" class="btn btn-default">Details</button></div>
```

Comment: Use an anchor link styled as the button. Change`button` to `a` and remove the `type` attribute.

Comment: is there a lot of data you want to pass or just some little  data?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Only two values, the ID and Category of current object.

Comment: pass them with $_GET

Comment: i'm gonna write you an example  in the answer area

Comment: @Marwelln I did what you said. But shouldn't I pass a value variable or anything else together with the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the $_GET variable like :

```
<div><button href = "Product_details.php?data1=value2&data2=value2" type="submit" name="Details" class="btn btn-default">Details</button></div>
```

> value1 and value2 are supposed as  two variables available in the
>   current php file which the button exist named $data1 and $data2

it's goning to be something like :

```
<div><button href = "Product_details.php?data1=<?php echo $data1?>&data2=<?echo $data2?>" type="submit" name="Details" class="btn btn-default">Details</button></div>
```

and in the Product_details.php , you can get you data as :

```
$data1 = $_GET['data1'];
$data2 = $_GET['data2'];
```

Comment: Thank you! Your method did worked, but only partial. I guess  Something's wrong with "Product_details.php?data1=value2&data2=value2". In the second php, I got only "$data1" and "$data2", not the values I expected. Any improvement?

Comment: can you test with using  bracket {}

Comment: Thank you. But I used another expression "Product_details.php?data1=<?php echo $data1;?>&data2=<?php echo $data2;?>". And everything's fine now!